# Dynamic id with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with AngularJS and I have a form with checkboxes that I generate with `ng-repeat`. I want to generate the id of each `checkbox` dynamically, I tried to do it like this:

```
<label ng-repeat="x in placeTypes">

    <input type="checkbox" id='{{x.value}}'>
    {{x.display}}
    <br>
</label>
```

But when I try to get the element by `Id` the element is `null`.

Comment: HTML tag attribute values should use double quotes. `id="{{x.value}}"`. Also, make sure `x.value` has been set.

Comment: You can use $index to track that value of `x` in your `ng-repeat` and assign `id={{$index}}`

Comment: I solved it with this: 

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        getPlaces();
    });

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    <label ng-repeat="x in placeTypes track by $index">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox{{$index}}">
       {{x.display}}
       <br>
   </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```
<label ng-repeat="x in placeTypes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{$index}}">
    {{x.display}}
  <br>
</label>
```

You can read more about ngRepeat in the Angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, https://plnkr.co/edit/mMzNGsEajOxY7TyiHArL?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .component('app', {
    template: `<label ng-repeat="x in $ctrl.placeTypes">

    <input type="checkbox" id='input-{{x.value}}' component-did-mount>
    {{x.display}}
    <br>
</label>`,
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.$onInit = () => {
        this.placeTypes = [{
          value: '1',
          display: 'hello'
        }, {
          value: '2',
          display: 'hello world'
        }]
        $scope.$on('componentDidMount', () => {
          const $el = document.getElementById('input-1');
          console.log('$el >>', $el);
        })
      }
    }
  }).directive('componentDidMount', ['$timeout', ($timeout) => {
    var def = {
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: false,
      link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
        $timeout(() => {
          scope.$emit('componentDidMount')
        });
      }
    };
    return def;
  }]);


angular.element(document).ready(() => {
  const bootstrapAngular = () => angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'], {});
  bootstrapAngular();
});
```